# Remove everything after first space occurs in sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

does anyone know how to remove everything after the first space occurs in sublime text 3.

For example i have this file:

abcde fghi jklm

And i would like to have this output:

abcde

Answer (score 5):

After searching a bit this is what worked for me:

In regular expression mode, search for:

\t.*

And replace with

Nothing

Answer (score 4):

And a few years later...

Tested on macOS:
Use <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to popup the Find/Replace dialog.
Make sure the `.*` button is on (this enables the Regex mode).

Find: `\ .*`
Replace: don't type anything here

Obs: the `\` in the regex is not strictly necessary, I just added it to emphasize the fact that there is a space in the string before the dot.

Obs2: the answer from the OP works only if you have tabs instead of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to replace with regex, and use:

- Find What:     `^(\S+)\s?[^\n]*\n`
- Replace With:  `\1`

Comment: I replaced the first line with the second one and all i got was an empty file, so this did not really work for me

Comment: When you press Ctrl+H you get two textboxes ("Find What" and "Replace with"). Well, the first line `^(\S+)\s?[^$]*` is for "Find What" and the 2nd line `\1` is  for "Replace With".

Comment: Yeah, I did just that but it removed everything in the file

Comment: I have changed regular expression a bit - please try it again?